# Drag and drop, ListView and item Views that miss the ACTION_DRAG_STARTED event

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-listview, recycle

On Android, I use a `ListView` and I want to be able to reorder its items using drag and drop. I know there are different implementation of a "drag and drop listview", however I want to use the [Drag and Drop framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) coming since **API level 11**.

It started very well until I wanted to scroll my `ListView` while doing a drag and drop. As it is written in the example below, for now, I check on top of which list element I am, so if its position is not between `ListView.getLastVisiblePosition()` and `ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` I use a `ListView.smoothScrollToPosition()` to view the other list items.

It is a first implementation but it works quite well.

The problem arises while scrolling: some elements do not answer to the drag and drop events - `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED` and the others - when I am on top of them. It is due to the way the ListView manages its item views: it tries to recycle the item views that are not visible any more.

It is all right and it works, but sometimes the `getView()` of the `ListAdapter` returns a new object. Since it is new, this object missed the `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` so it does not answer to the other `DragEvent` events!

Here is an example. In this case, if I start a drag and drop with a long click on a list item and if I drag it, the majority of items will have a green background if I am on top of them ; but some don't.

Any idea about making them subscribe to the Drag and drop event mechanism even if they missed `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`?

```
// Somewhere I have a ListView that use the MyViewAdapter
// MyListView _myListView = ...
// _myListView.setAdapter(new MyViewAdapter(getActivity(), ...));
_myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, _myListView.getItemAtPosition(position), 0);
        return true;
    }
});

class MyViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyElement> {

    public MyViewAdapter(Context context, List<TimedElement> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myElementView = convertView;
        if (myElementView == null) {
            /* If the code is executed here while scrolling with a drag and drop,
             * the new view is not associated to the current drag and drop events */
            Log.d("app", "Object created!");
            // Create view
            // myElementView = ...
            // Prepare drag and drop
            myElementView.setOnDragListener(new MyElementDragListener());
        }
        // Associates view and position in ListAdapter, needed for drag and drop
        myElementView.setTag(R.id.item_position, position);
        // Continue to prepare view
        // ...
        return timedElementView;
    }

    private class MyElementDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch(action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                v.invalidate();
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                int targetPosition = (Integer)v.getTag(R.id.item_position);
                if (event.getY() < v.getHeight()/2 ) {
                    Log.i("app", "top "+targetPosition);        
                }
                else {
                    Log.i("app", "bottom "+targetPosition);
                }
                // To scroll in ListView while doing drag and drop
                if (targetPosition > _myListView.getLastVisiblePosition()-2) {
                    _myListView.smoothScrollToPosition(targetPosition+2);
                }
                else if (targetPosition < _myListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()+2) {
                    _myListView.smoothScrollToPosition(targetPosition-2);
                }
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                v.invalidate();
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            default:
               break;
            }
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not solved this recycling problem, but I found a possible workaround still using the Drag & Drop framework. The idea is to change of perspective: instead of using a `OnDragListener` on each `View` in the list, it can be used on the `ListView` directly.

Then the idea is to find on top of which item the finger is while doing the Drag & Drop, and to write the related display code in the `ListAdapter` of the `ListView`. The trick is then to find on top of which item view we are, and where the drop is done.

In order to do that, I set as an `id` to each view created by the adapter its `ListView` position - with `View.setId()`, so I can find it later using a combination of `ListView.pointToPosition()` and `ListView.findViewById()`.

As a drag listener example (which is, I remind you, applied on the `ListView`), it can be something like that:

```
// Initalize your ListView
private ListView _myListView = new ListView(getContext());

// Start drag when long click on a ListView item
_myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, _myListView.getItemAtPosition(position), 0);
        return true;
    }
});

// Set the adapter and drag listener
_myListView.setOnDragListener(new MyListViewDragListener());
_myListView.setAdapter(new MyViewAdapter(getActivity()));

// Classes used above

private class MyViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
    public MyViewAdapter (Context context, List<TimedElement> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myView = convertView;
        if (myView == null) {
            // Instanciate your view
        }
        // Associates view and position in ListAdapter, needed for drag and drop
        myView.setId(position);
        return myView;
    }
}


private class MyListViewDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_DROP:
                // We drag the item on top of the one which is at itemPosition
                int itemPosition = _myListView.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                // We can even get the view at itemPosition thanks to get/setid
                View itemView = _myListView.findViewById(itemPosition );
                /* If you try the same thing in ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION, itemView
                 * is sometimes null; if you need this view, just return if null.
                 * As the same event is then fired later, only process the event
                 * when itemView is not null.
                 * It can be more problematic in ACTION_DRAG_DROP but for now
                 * I never had itemView null in this event. */
                // Handle the drop as you like
                return true;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not try this but who know maybe someday I will. This seems a real good work, and quite technical!  Upvote from me.

Comment: Perfect, this works just as well for `RecyclerView`, except you need to use `findChildViewUnder` instead of `pointToPosition`.